# How do I apply for an ancestry visa with my family?

Tags: uk-visa, ancestry-visas, ancestry

We are a family of three (two adults and one newborn). I intend to apply for an ancestry visa based on my grandfather's birth in the UK. Do I need to fill in a separate application for my husband and my 3 month old baby?
If yes, do I mention my grandfather's details in their application?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your family members will need to submit their own applications as your dependents. The details are [here](https://www.gov.uk/ancestry-visa/family-members).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).